# 413 - Failed to load admin-ajex.php (Nginx + WordPress + Divi)

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress

I am running Wordpress 5.2.2 dockerized on nginx 1.13.1 with PHP Version 7.3

When I try to activate/download a premade theme from Divi I get 413 Errors like:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4 POST https://hwc.mountdev.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 413
```

or

```
admin-ajax.php:1 Failed to load resource. The server responded with a status of 413()
```

As 413 says, I tried to increase my PHP Values to recommended ones by the Theme, after this did not help either, I increased them to ridiculous values. Did not help either.

```
## System Status ##

  PHP Version
  7.3

  memory_limit
  256M

  post_max_size
  100M

  max_execution_time
  300

  upload_max_filesize
  64M

  max_input_time
  1000

  max_input_vars
  1000
```

I have no idea what the problem could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server most likely refers to the nginx reverse proxy layer rather than PHP. Check and increase the value of `client_max_body_size` in your config file. nginx defaults to [1MB as the max limit](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size).

Don't forget to reload the config for it to become active

Comment: Thank you! In addition for other people: You need to add this in the `location`, `http`, or `server` block of your configuration.